# Putting a sql table into python error. Whats wrong?

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I would like to know what's going on with this query. Im not able of put it into a pandas data frame. The error description is "IndexError: tuple index out of range"

```
  i = 3
  query = ("SELECT COL1, COL2"
  "FROM whatever "
  " where SUBSTR(DATE,1,{}) = '201901' ").format(i)

   df = pd.read_sql(query,con)
```

The problem is with the format. I need to put the "i" inside the query to take different dates and later ill group them in a dataframe.

Comment: You should include the full stack trace

Comment: Please post a complete reproducible test case - a whole program - possibly with a much shorter and more comprehensible query.

Comment: Done, thanks for the advice

Comment: "IndexError: tuple index out of range" doesn't sound like an Oracle error. ???

Comment: It has to be with the .format()

Comment: Perhaps the issue is that you have `i = 3`. Does the query produce 3 rows out output? What happens if you set i to 1 instead of 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, you got two problems, the first one is a typo:
you forgot to add a space after the concatenation, so it won't find any columns

```
i = 3
query = ("SELECT COL1, COL2" # Here you forgot to add a space, the interpreter will read it as COL2FROM
"FROM whatever "
"where SUBSTR(DATE,1,{}) = '201901' ").format(i)

df = pd.read_sql(query,con)
```

The second thing, what you did with SUBSTR will not return anything at all, because it will only return 3 characters, and you comparing it to 6, so change the `i` to 6 or make it dynamic.
Also, before doing anything on the resulted table, I would suggest you get the length of it, by using the `len(df)` function, so it should look like this:

```
i = 6
query = ("SELECT COL1, COL2 "
"FROM whatever "
"where SUBSTR(DATE,1,{}) = '201901' ").format(i)

df = pd.read_sql(query,con)
if len(df):
    print(df[0]) # Prints the first item
else
    print("No items were found")
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is (looking at the query in your original question before your edit), you have two string replacements but only one value in your format() method call. If you want to insert i into both of the '{}' in your query, you should change them to {0}. Also, just a tip, save yourself some trouble and use ''' for multi-line strings.

```
for i in [1,2,3,4]:
    query = ('''SELECT FORMALIZADO, AMORTIZADO, PDT_AMORTIZACION, LSCRV, SUM(DESCUBIERTO) AS T_FORMALIZADO, SUM(CAPITAL_PENDIENTE) AS T_PDT_AMORTIZACION, COUNT(*) as CASOS "
             FROM
             (SELECT
                CASE WHEN DESCUBIERTO <= 1000 THEN 1000
                WHEN DESCUBIERTO >= 1001 AND DESCUBIERTO <=2000 THEN 2000 
                WHEN DESCUBIERTO >=2001 AND DESCUBIERTO <=3000 THEN 3000 
                WHEN DESCUBIERTO >= 3001 AND DESCUBIERTO <= 4000 THEN 4000
                WHEN DESCUBIERTO >= 4001 AND DESCUBIERTO <=5000 THEN 5000 
                WHEN DESCUBIERTO >=5001 AND DESCUBIERTO <=6000 THEN 6000 
                WHEN DESCUBIERTO >= 6001 AND DESCUBIERTO <= 7000 THEN 7000
                WHEN DESCUBIERTO >= 7001 AND DESCUBIERTO <=8000 THEN 8000 
                WHEN DESCUBIERTO >=8001 AND DESCUBIERTO <=9000 THEN 9000 
                WHEN DESCUBIERTO >= 9001 AND DESCUBIERTO <= 10000 THEN 10000 
                WHEN DESCUBIERTO >= 10001 AND DESCUBIERTO <=11000 THEN 11000 
                WHEN DESCUBIERTO >=11001 AND DESCUBIERTO <=12000 THEN 12000 
                WHEN DESCUBIERTO >= 12001 AND DESCUBIERTO <= 13000 THEN 13000 
                WHEN DESCUBIERTO >= 13001 AND DESCUBIERTO <= 14000 THEN 14000 
                WHEN DESCUBIERTO >= 14001 AND DESCUBIERTO <=15000 THEN 15000 
                WHEN DESCUBIERTO >= 15001 THEN 15001 
                ELSE NULL END AS FORMALIZADO, 
                CASE WHEN CAPITAL_PENDIENTE / NULLIF(DESCUBIERTO,0) <= 0.25 THEN 'Q1' 
                WHEN CAPITAL_PENDIENTE / NULLIF(DESCUBIERTO,0) >= 0.26 AND CAPITAL_PENDIENTE / NULLIF(DESCUBIERTO,0)  <= 0.50 THEN 'Q2' 
                WHEN CAPITAL_PENDIENTE / NULLIF(DESCUBIERTO,0) >= 0.51 AND CAPITAL_PENDIENTE / NULLIF(DESCUBIERTO,0)  <= 0.75 THEN 'Q3' 
                WHEN CAPITAL_PENDIENTE / NULLIF(DESCUBIERTO,0) >= 0.76 AND CAPITAL_PENDIENTE / NULLIF(DESCUBIERTO,0) <= 1 THEN 'Q4' 
                ELSE NULL END AS AMORTIZADO, 
                CASE WHEN (1-CAPITAL_PENDIENTE / NULLIF(DESCUBIERTO,0)) <= 0.25 THEN 'Q1' 
                WHEN (1-CAPITAL_PENDIENTE / NULLIF(DESCUBIERTO,0)) >= 0.26 AND (1-CAPITAL_PENDIENTE / NULLIF(DESCUBIERTO,0))  <= 0.50 THEN 'Q2'
                WHEN (1-CAPITAL_PENDIENTE / NULLIF(DESCUBIERTO,0)) >= 0.51 AND (1-CAPITAL_PENDIENTE / NULLIF(DESCUBIERTO,0))  <= 0.75 THEN 'Q3'
                WHEN (1-CAPITAL_PENDIENTE / NULLIF(DESCUBIERTO,0)) >= 0.76 AND (1-CAPITAL_PENDIENTE / NULLIF(DESCUBIERTO,0)) <= 1 THEN 'Q4'
                ELSE NULL END AS PDT_AMORTIZACION,
                L.LSCRV, DESCUBIERTO, CAPITAL_PENDIENTE
                FROM ON5H C LEFT JOIN CRV L ON SUBSTR(L.CLIENTE, 1,12) = C.CLIENTE
                WHERE SUBSTR(C.FCH_FINANCIACION,1,6) = TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,{0}),'YYYYMM') AND NOMBRE_PRODUCTO = 'YM' AND TO_CHAR(C.FECHA_BASE, 'YYYYMM') = TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,{0}),'YYYYMM') AND POSIC_ACTUAL = '010')
             GROUP BY LSCRV, FORMALIZADO, PDT_AMORTIZACION, AMORTIZADO
             ORDER BY LSCRV''').format(i)
```